# Lumix G85 - Black Corner regardless of lens and no hood - please help

Tags: dslr, sensor, optics, mirrorless

I have owned a Panasonic Lumix G85 for about a year. This month, I've started getting a black area on the left corner of my images, which you can also see on the EVF.

[image: Example Here]

I can't see anything on the sensor and this never used to happen before. Can anyone help me? I'd hate to think my camera is no good.

I've heard that sensor repairs are extremely expensive but I have no idea what I would actually be looking at.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: When examining your camera's shutter and sensor, don't forget that the image projected by the lens is inverted. The anomaly visible along the lower left edge in the photo will be on the upper left edge of your camera's sensor as viewed from *behind* the camera, and thus along the upper right edge as viewed by looking through the front of the camera with the lens removed.

Answer (score 1):

More likely a problem with the shutter that doesn't completely uncover the sensor. From the look of it the curtain wouldn't remain horizontal and jams.

Has the shutter noise changed lately?